# How to prove that set A is Lebeg measurable?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm wondering how to solve this.
We have an infinite countable set A ⊂ R is such that λ * (A) =0,
. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: And by the way, all countable sets have outer measure $0$ in Euclidean space.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  *Lebesgue* (pronounced like Lebeg) was a French mathematician

Answer (score -2):

Any countable set is measurable since it is a countable union of singletons, which are measurable.